# ANTLR parser, can I stop at first match?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I’m playing with ANTLR to write a parser for PDF object structure, but I encounter a problem to parse a string stream mixed with PDF Reference and Integer.

Basically, a PDF Reference is a string like this: "10 0 R" (INTEGER SPACE INTEGER SPACE ‘R’).

Here's my grammar file (simplified):

```
grammar Pdf;

options {
language=CSharp3;
backtrack=true;
}

public r returns [string val]
    :   ref {$val = $r.text;}
    |   INTEGER {$val = $r.text;}
    ;

ref
    :   INTEGER SPACE INTEGER SPACE 'R';

INTEGER
    :   DIGIT+;

SPACE: ' ';

fragment DIGIT
    :   '0'..'9'
    ;
```

Here's the test code (in C#):

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("97 98 10 0 R 100 101");
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

ANTLRInputStream inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream(stream);
PdfLexer lexer = new PdfLexer(inputStream);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

PdfParser parser = new PdfParser(tokens);
string result = parser.r();
```

I expect result to be the first rule matched in rule r (be it ref or INTEGER).

For example:

- if input="97 98 10 0 R 100 101": result="97"
- if input="10 0 R 100 101": result="10 0 R"

No need to go through the whole string stream. Just match first rule, then stop.

I'm newbie to ANTLR and couldn't figure it out how to do it. 
I'm using ANTLRWorks 1.4.3 and antlr-dotnet-csharpruntime-3.4.1.9004.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`backtrack=true` only applies to parser rules: not lexer rules. So when the lexer stumbles upon `INTEGER SPACE` followed by something *other* than `INTEGER`, the lexer will throw an error/exception: it will ***not*** backtrack in the `REF` rule and create an `INTEGER` and `SPACE` token instead.

But `REF` shouldn't be a lexer rule to begin with, but a parser rule instead:

```
ref
 : INTEGER SPACE INTEGER SPACE 'R'
 ;
```

### Edit

I'm on Linux, and can therefore not test the C# target (at least, I've never been able to get the `CSharp3` target running inside MonoDevelop). But here's a Java demo:

```java
grammar Pdf;

public r
 : ( ref     {System.out.println("ref     = '" + $ref.text + "'");}
   | INTEGER {System.out.println("INTEGER = '" + $INTEGER.text + "'");}
   | SPACE   {System.out.println("SPACE   = '" + $SPACE.text + "'");}
   )*
   EOF
 ;

ref
 : INTEGER SPACE INTEGER SPACE 'R'
 ;

INTEGER
 : DIGIT+;

SPACE
 : ' '
 ;

fragment DIGIT
 : '0'..'9'
 ;
```

You can test the parser with the class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PdfLexer lexer = new PdfLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("97 98 10 0 R 100 101"));
    PdfParser parser = new PdfParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.r();
  }
}
```

and if you run this class, the following is printed:

```
INTEGER = '97'
SPACE   = ' '
INTEGER = '98'
SPACE   = ' '
ref     = '10 0 R'
SPACE   = ' '
INTEGER = '100'
SPACE   = ' '
INTEGER = '101'
```

which is exactly as I expected.

Comment: I changed REF to ref, but it didn't work. 
Though there's something different, now the tokens became:
97, SPACE, 98, SPACE, 10, SPACE, 0, SPACE, 'R', SPACE, 101, EOF.

It only recognize INTEGER, not ref.

Comment: @sun1991, everything works just fine when I test it. See my **EDIT**.

Comment: @Kiers, I can duplicate the result on my machine under C# output, which is a big step for me, thank you! Sorry I didn't make it clear in my question, but my original intention is not use rule r:(...)* to go through all string stream. I'd like r() to return just first rule it matches, be it ref or INTEGER. If input is "10 0 R 100 101", it should return "ref=10 0 R" and stop, if input is "97 98 10 0 R", it just return "INTEGER=97" and stop. I tries to remove the brackets and * around rule r, but again, it failed to return anything.